# Why is $n \ge 2$ not mentioned instead of $n \ge 3$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

In Dummit  and foote book it is  written that for any $n \ge 3$,  $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic

I understand the proof  of  $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic for $n \ge3$

Bu i think $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is also  not cyclic for $n \ge2$

For $n=2$

Take the  subgroups  generated  by $2^n-1$  and $2^{n-1} +1$

Now put $ n=2$ then $ 2^2-1=3\equiv1 \mod(2^2) \implies3^2=9=1 \mod4$

similarly $2^{2-1} +1 =3\equiv1 \mod(2^2) \implies3^2=9=1 \mod4$

Both  element are distinct element of   $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and have same order  $2$

Therefore for any $n \ge 2$,  $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^\times=\{1,3\}$, so is a group of order $2$.

Comment: Why does those two elements having the order mean that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is not cyclic?  Is that the definition of non-cyclic?

Comment: Note that $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic with $3$ as a generator.  Did you ever write out the multiplication table for the group?

Comment: All groups of order $2$ are cyclic.

Comment: @Randall these element generate  two different  subgroup  of order $2$

Comment: The order of $1$ is $1$.  The identity element always has order $1$.

Comment: Also, why do you claim that "both element are distinct element" when you also showed in the line above that they are both $3$, so definitely not distinct?

Comment: You  are right @Randall Actually ,i  thought that $2^2-1$ and $2^{2-1}   +1$  are distinct

Comment: @lulu  but $1^4=1$ this implies  identity  has order $4$

Comment: That is NOT the definition of order.  We also have $1^{103}=1$, so is the order $103$?

Comment: I think you need to review the basic definitions.  Look up what the order of an element means.  And write out examples!  Don't just guess at things.  Write out the multiplication table explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $G=(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)^{\times}$, we have the Cayley table

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\times_4 & 1+4\Bbb Z & 3+4\Bbb Z\\
\hline
1+4\Bbb Z & 1+4\Bbb Z & 3+4\Bbb Z\\
3+4\Bbb Z & 3+4\Bbb Z & 1+4\Bbb Z
\end{array}.$$

Thus $G$ is cyclic with generator $3+4\Bbb Z$.